# System user permissions for Apache2 files

Tags: linux, apache, permissions

How to make normal system user permissible for all files created by apache?

I set the www-data group as primiary group for user, but this still doesnt work :/

Created directory (by www-data) have 755 chmods, files have 644.
I dont want to change directories/files permissions every time I want to do something by the user.

Comment: Take a look at the `umask` command. You must change the umask of the web server so that it creates files and directories with other permissions.